# tfs2012 mvc buld template issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, templates, tfs

Have a new MVC 4 project in TFS 2012 with an issue that 4 hours of searching cant solve.

When I attempt to set up a Build Definition for that MVC project, the default template is not picked up automatically. And no templates are displayed in the dropdown (even after a refresh).  The templates are present in the Build Template folder for the MVC project.

Thinking it might be an issue with the project collection, I added a web project and a windows form project to the collection. I was able to add a build definition for both of those projects successfully. In both cases, the default template was recognized and automatically included in the Build Definition.

Currently running latest version TFS 2012.
I am an Administrator for that TFS installation.

Q 1) Am I missing a template? If so, where would I find it?

Q 2) Did I miss a Configuration setting or settings which I need to correct/verify?

Q 3) if not one of the first two questions, Then what do I need to do to fix this?

Thanks,

Robert

Comment: Have resolved issue: <BR>Problem stemmed from having multiple solution in project collection project.<BR>TFS 2012 assumes 'BuildProcessTemplates' is within the solution having a Build Definition created. <BR> The Fix is: Separated solutions into individual Project Collection projects. Its not the best solution but it will work for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to open `Team Explorer`, right click on `Collection Team Project`, an click on `Team Project Collection Settings`, go to `Process Template Manager`.

On the `Dialog` opened , Choose for example `MSF for Agile Software Development V5.0` and select link `Download`. After the folder is downloaded, open `\Build\Templates`, add `DefaultTemplate.xaml and UpgradeTemplate.xaml`.